# Where do Minecraft texture packs go on OS X?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, technical-issues, mods, macos

I play Minecraft on OS X and for some reason clicking this button doesn't do anything.

[image: Screenshot of "Open texture pack folder" button]

Where should I be putting my texture packs?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I poked around and discovered a new folder:

**~/Library/Application Support/minecraft/texturepacks/**

Putting the texture packs you download in this folder makes them appear in the menu. Don't extract the files, just leave the .zip there.

Answer (score 2):

Previous to this update, you would put Minecraft.app into a folder called "Minecraft" along with all the files for the texture pack, and launch Minecraft.app from there. However, I don't know if this is still the case with this version.

<sub>(The button also doesn't do anything for me.)</sub>

Comment: This worked for me. However, with the update, I suspect that Brant's answer would be the place to put them in the future. It's possible that this method may go away in favour of the updated method.

Comment: Yeah, it's probably better to use Brant's method instead.

Answer (score 1):

How to install Minecraft texture packs - Mac OS:

1. Open finder.
2. On the top of the screen click "Go"
3. There will be a list of items drop down.
4. Hold down the alt / Option Key.
5. There should be a "Library" button that appears.
6. Click on "Library" and hold down alt / Option Key.
7. Open the "Application Support" Folder
8. Then open the "Minecraft" Folder.
9. Then open the "Resourcepacks" Folder.
10. Put your Minecraft TexturePack in there.

That is where to put the texture pack in.

Answer (score 0):

I just got busy understanding a bit about what can be done with Mac OS X in terms of resources for changing skins or textures. Sadly most of the resources one finds by googling are for Window OSes. However upon digging deeper (pun intended) to help my 11 yo i found a couple of links that should be of help for Mac players of Minecraft as well a few directions that can help.

Skins:

very simply find any skin that has the .png extension (image file) then log at www.minecraft.net with your account. Once in click on your profile, in there you will find the option to upload  new images for a new skin (i.e. your downloaded/created .png file).
the boave is a summirized version of waht I found at www.tumblr.com/tagged/install+texture+packs+minecraft

Textures:

I am not completely done yet but should you find any texture package you like that is donwloadable as .zip file you can simply take it. By default should end up in your "downloads" folder inside your user "home folder" (look for the little home icon). IN the same user home folder you will find the 'Library' folder. click it open and then locate and open the "applications support" folder inside it. Here once open you will find the Minecraft folder...open it and you will see several folders one of which is the 'texturepacks' folder.
Click and hold your mouse on the downloaded texture .zip file and drag and drop it in the 'texturepacks' folder.
at this point you are in business...just launch minecraft and select the option for textures once you have logged in. In addition to the default texture now you will see the new one(s) you have added and u can simply click on the one you want to try. Once you selected it you can just launch the game and enjoy.

MCPatcher HD

You have probably found out a gazillion sites where to download this, the only issue being it is an .exe file for Window OSes. I still have not figured out if it is really necessary to use it when using the Mac OS version of the game (probably so if the packs you have downloaded require to adjust the tile size to something else rather than the default 16x16 pixels). However here is where to get the .jar version of it if you need it. I tried it and it works although it gives an error message before opening the interface to change tile size and upload the texture files.

http://uploaded.to/file/l4gk5p

Should I find more about anything of the above I will make sure to update this entry.
Good luck and enjoy!

Comment: Once you are in the Minecraft directory it should all be the same as on Windows and Linux.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same question and found the answer only by try'n'error.

The correct directory is (please forgive me translation errors):
/User/YourName/Library/Application Support/minetest

In this directory you should see cache, client and world directory. Here create a textures directory. Inside of that create another one (mostly they say you should name it "all", I think this is user defined). Anyway, into this directory place all the files in and restart minetest.

Comment: I think you're confused, and this answer does not apply. [Minetest](http://www.minetest.net/) is not Minecraft.

Answer (score -1):

If you're on a Mac or running OS X, all you have to do is download the pack and put the application into a folder with the texture pack.

Comment: I just tested this out by putting Minecraft.app in a folder with a bunch of texture packs, and it doesn't work. The texture packs don't appear in the menu.

Comment: @brant If there was a `texturepack` directory inside of the Minecraft.app bundle then you could try to put it there.